# Cannot set min/max on highcharts with yearly series

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I thought I was getting better at highcharts but have now stumbled on an annoying issue, where I cannot seem to be able to set the xAxis min and max values where the xAxis is composed of years. I cannot find a similar issue online.

What happens is the chart xAxis plots the years as expected ... but the series simply vanish and there is no yAxis on the chart.

This is how I have set up my xAxis options ... Has anybody got any idea as to why this is going on? Thank you all for your time.

```
xAxis: {
        min: 2010,
        max: 2030,
        categories: [1980,  1981,   1982,   1983,   1984,   1985,   1986,   1987,   1988,   1989,   1990,   1991,   1992,   1993,   1994,   1995,   1996,   1997,   1998,   1999,   2000,   2001,   2002,   2003,   2004,   2005,   2006,   2007,   2008,   2009,   2010,   2011,   2012,   2013,   2014,   2015,   2016,   2017,   2018,   2019,   2020,   2021,   2022,   2023,   2024,   2025,   2026,   2027,   2028,   2029,   2030,   2031,   2032,   2033,   2034,   2035,   2036,   2037,   2038,   2039,   2040]
        },
        series: [ (I have removed them from the example) ]
    };
```

Comment: are you looking for [http://jsfiddle.net/fbbGY/2678/](http://jsfiddle.net/fbbGY/2678/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, the options `min` & `max` use the index and not the key of your array. Replace `2010` by `30` and `2030` by `50`, this should be working!

Or use the function [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) :

```
var yourArray = [1980,  1981,   1982,   1983,   1984,   1985,   1986,   1987,   1988,   1989,   1990,   1991,   1992,   1993,   1994,   1995,   1996,   1997,   1998,   1999,   2000,   2001,   2002,   2003,   2004,   2005,   2006,   2007,   2008,   2009,   2010,   2011,   2012,   2013,   2014,   2015,   2016,   2017,   2018,   2019,   2020,   2021,   2022,   2023,   2024,   2025,   2026,   2027,   2028,   2029,   2030,   2031,   2032,   2033,   2034,   2035,   2036,   2037,   2038,   2039,   2040]

.
. //Define your highcharts options
.

    xAxis: {
        min: yourArray.indexOf(2010),
        max: yourArray.indexOf(2030),
        categories: yourArray
    },
    series: [ (I have removed them from the example) ]
};
```

Comment: That is perfect. I needed to reference the index, not the 'key'. Thank you so much R3tep.